# Error Messages after updating Project Configuration via Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm developing a project using Maven. After a while i did "update Project Configuration" within my IDE (Springsource Tool Suite). Now my IDE is complaining, that there are some errors, that have not been here before.
The curious thing is, that the error messages seem to be wrong. In the below code it says, that I have to remove the @override Annotation, because a superclass has to be overriden (which i'm actually doing?)

```
 package org.powertac.humanbroker.services;

        import javax.jms.JMSException;
        import javax.jms.Message;
        import javax.jms.MessageListener;
        import javax.jms.TextMessage;            
        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class JMSMessageListenerDecorator  implements MessageListener{

        private static final Logger Log =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSMessageListenerDecorator.class);
        private BaseMessageListener messageListener = null;

        public JMSMessageListenerDecorator(BaseMessageListener l){
            messageListener = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                try {                               
                    if(Log.isDebugEnabled())
                        Log.debug("Received message "+ message.toString()+" from JMS.");

                    messageListener.onMessage(((TextMessage) message).getText());
                } catch (Exception e){ 
                    Log.error ("The original message leading up to the exception reads ${message.text}.", e);
                }
            } else {
                Log.error ("The JMS Listener knows only how to react to TextMessage objects.");
            }

        }

    }
```

[image: error message]

Any Idea what I could do the make the error messages vanish? Thx

PS: I got about 5 error messages in 3 different classes and all complain about the @Override Annotation.

---

### UPDATE

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <name>xyz</name>
  <description>xyz</description>
  <repositories>
      <repository>  
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository>  
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Communication to  Server -->

      <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>activecluster</groupId>
    <artifactId>activecluster</artifactId>
    <version>20040423.075722</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javacc</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <!-- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JAXEN-217 -->
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


    <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- PrimeFaces component library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-interface</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <reporting>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
  </reporting>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</springframework-version>
    <springwebflow-version>2.3.0.RELEASE</springwebflow-version>
    <springsecurity-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Check your JDK version, if its not 6+, you see this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pom.xml, you'll want something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Your current pom.xml is likely configuring your project for Java 5 (probably by default), where you are using Java 6's language semantics.  If you configure everything to be for Java 6, you should be all set.

Comment: hmm... I included your code in my pom.xml and again did a "update project config", but unfortunately it's not working. The error message stays the same...

Comment: Can you validate what Eclipse thinks the Java version is set to?  Right-click on the project, Properties, Java Compiler, then look under "JDK Compliance" in the content pane?  If it's still set to 1.5, I'd need to see your entire pom.xml.  Is it possible this snippet was included in the wrong spot?  (It needs to be within the <build>/<plugins>.)

Comment: :D there was a checkbox called "use compliance from execution environment 'J2SE-1.5' on the Java Build Path". I unchecked that and manually selected "Compiler Compliance Level: 1.6". Now it's working! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I wouldn't consider this solved.  That "use compliance form execution environment" value is exactly what should be set from Maven.  I assume you're using m2e for Maven integration with Eclipse?  If so, make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: mhm... guess you're right.. I reopened the question and will update my original post with my pom file....

Comment: I don't see a <build> section at all.  Please review my updated snippet (included additional parent tags), include into yours, re-test (re-configure the project with Maven), then post your updated pom.xml if you're still having issues.

Comment: And of course: now it works as it should! Thank you veeery much! Answered!